# Difference between deallocating a single variable or array in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic

I'm studying about `new` and `new[]` from [learncpp](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/69-dynamic-memory-allocation-with-new-and-delete/) and there is one small detail in the site, which isn't clear enough for me. The following picture will explain my question:

[image]

So do we have to set the array-pointer also to 0 after we have deallocated it like in the single variable case? Is this a requirement or is the procedure different with `delete` and `delete[]`?

Thnx for any help! =)

Comment: new and new[] should be avoided at all cost. use std::vector (or any suitable containers) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very depends what you are planning to do further in the code. Setting a pointer to to NULL/nullptr after deleting the object it used to point to (regardless whether it is a pointer pointing to the array or to the singular variable), is done purely to mark a pointer as deallocated ,so you can easily check if that pointer is still 'active' or not by :

```
if (pnArray != nullptr) 
{
  // now it is safe to dereference the pointer
}
```

If the double deletion occurs in the code (shouldn't be the case), calling a delete operator on nullptr will not crash the program (double deletion may bring significant amount of pain: it may crash the application, corrupt the  heap, make some changes to the objects already allocated on the heap..) :

```
delete pnValue;
pnValue = nullptr;
....
delete pnValue; // safe to delete ( still it's not no-op )
```

You don't need to set the pointers to nullptr-s if you delete the class members in it's destructor for instance (as that pointers will not be used anymore).

These are the raw pointers, maybe have a look also at the smart pointers, which are in general much safer option

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help! =) @AdaRRR by the way, one more question. Does nullptr == 0 in C++ ?

Comment: "A null-pointer constant is either an integral constant expression that evaluates to zero (such as 0 or 0L), or a value of type nullptr_t (such as nullptr)."http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/NULL/), so it is true to say: if (nullptr == 0) { (...) } or char * p = nullptr;  if (p == 0) {..} . However it is just a better practice to use nullptr(if working with c++11) or NULL otherwise

Comment: +1 Roger that :) I will use nullptr instead of 0 =) Appreciate the help! :)

Comment: This: _"prevention against a double deletion"_ is a fool's errand. Double deletion is a serious program error. Without wanting to libel Mr. Stroustrup, it is my guess that he was high when he had the "deleting nullpointer is a no-op" idea. This is **not** a prevention, nor a fix. It is a technique to **hide** errornous behavior, making it undetectable and untraceable. Double deletion **should** crash.

Comment: hmm, true. I didn't mean recommending it, it's a buggy situation/logic. But the fact is that this will prevent the heap corruption/crash. Maybe I will rephrase it.. Deleting a NULL pointer is specified as 'having no effect', not as being a no-op as far as I know. THX

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to set a pointer to zero after any deallocation. This is simply done to make it easy to tell that the pointer no longer points to anything.